# Mojolicious - how to intercept the incoming request before controller method handles and renders

Tags: perl, mojolicious

In Mojolicious app, I need to figure out which controller method will be handling the incoming request so that I can log details of the remote client and add some logic. I want to do it at only one place and not in every controller methods. I have tried some of the [HOOKS](https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious#HOOKS) but could not figure out. Much appreciate any help on this.

Routes are generated/created from several [OpenApi Plugin](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Plugin::OpenAPI) files and also use [Oauth2 Plugin](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OAuth2::AuthorizationServer) for OAuth.

- Mojolicious detail:

```
CORE
  Perl        (v5.16.3, linux)
  Mojolicious (8.22, Supervillain)

OPTIONAL
  Cpanel::JSON::XS 4.04+  (n/a)
  EV 4.0+                 (4.22)
  IO::Socket::Socks 0.64+ (n/a)
  IO::Socket::SSL 2.009+  (2.060)
  Net::DNS::Native 0.15+  (n/a)
  Role::Tiny 2.000001+    (2.000005)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked in [mojolicious mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mojolicious/6PMIsTspHxI) and got the reply from the creator of the Mojolicious, Sebastian Riedel. Thanks.

For everybody's benifit. `$c->match->stack` in `around_action` hook has the info I was looking for.

## Here is how:

In your application `startup` method:

```
sub startup {
    my $self = shift;
    ...
        $self->hook(
            around_action => sub {
                my ($next, $c, $action, $last) = @_;
                use DDP;
                p $c->match; 
                # prints all the info about the controller and the method/action
                # it is going to call
                ...
            }
        );
    ...
}
```

#### DDP - Output

```
Mojolicious::Routes::Match  {
    Parents       Mojo::Base
    public methods (7) : endpoint, find, has, path_for, position, root, stack
    private methods (1) : _match
    internals: {
        endpoint   Mojolicious::Routes::Route,
        position   0,
        root       Mojolicious::Routes,
        stack      [
            [0] {
                action               "controller_method_name",
                controller           "ControllerClassName",
                handler              "openapi",
                id                   3336,
                openapi.object       Mojolicious::Plugin::OpenAPI,
                openapi.op_path      [
                    [0] "paths",
                    [1] "/api/endpoint/path/{id}/status",
                    [2] "get"
                ],
                openapi.parameters   [
                    [0] {
                        description   "job id",
                        in            "path",
                        name          "id",
                        required      JSON::PP::Boolean,
                        type          "number"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

#### Here is the info I am looking for in `$c->match->stack`:

```
               action               "controller_method_name",
               controller           "ControllerClassName",
```

Comment: you could simply accept your own answer, if it really solved the problem defined in your question ...